# ing clauses coordination

Tags: american-english, british-english

-ing co-ordination

He returned and closed the front door, *making sure it was unlocked.*

We play a fun game, *trying to remember the day’s coaching tips.*

The bullet missed, *passing over his head*

How do these types of clauses 'coordinate' and why doesn't this one work the same way.

The finished painting, ***stunning than ever***

Comment: The last one is not grammatical.

Comment: Is "the finished painting" a typo for "**they** finished painting"?

Answer (score 2):

**stunning** is an adjective, and so it must modify a noun or be predicated of it; it does not coordinate with the main clause. And there is no main clause in that sentence to coordinate with in the first place ( **finished** is also an adjective), only a noun-phrase, "the finished painting".

Answer (score 2):

The last sentence is not grammatical. Also, only a person can be "more stunning than ever" because a person can be seen in different outfits or looking different on different occasions.

If you say the painting is stunning, that's OK but it can't be **more than ever** because then it would sound like a person or that it had a make-over.

Here's a transformation to see how this pattern works:

1) He returned and closed the front door, making sure it was unlocked.

1.a) He returned, closed the front door and made sure it was unlocked.

2) We played a fun game, trying to remember the day’s coaching tips.
2.a) We played a fun game and tried to remember the day's coaching tips. [as we did so].

3) The bullet missed him, passing over his head.
3.a) The bullet missed him and passed over this head.

With this one: The finished painting, stunning than ever

you can't do that. First, it is not a sentence with a subject, verb and object.

"The finished painting and stunned more than ever." is a no-go.

And this: The painting was finished, stunning more than ever. is poor semantically as explained above.

The painting was finished and was more stunning than ever.

compare that to:

The bride was dressed, more stunning than ever.=
The bride was dressed and was more stunning than ever.

The last one works.

Comment: I think you're right that you can't say *more stunning than ever* about things that don't change. But I don't think that's necessarily restricted to people. For instance: *the trees were covered in brightly coloured fall leaves, more stunning than ever.*

Comment: @Jason, sure but then stunning is an adjective, not a verb, as in: he stunned the rabbit with his hoe by mistake,

Comment: Hmm. But I don't consider the *bride* being (looking) stunning as being any different than the *tree* being (looking) stunning. However you want to interpret the grammar. (Or *the bride stunned me with her dress* versus *the tree stunned me with its colourful leaves*.) I can replace one with the other and have everything function the same way. (Although, again, *more* only works when there is a comparison to a previous state.)

Comment: stunning would have to be an action verb to work: "The car, stunning the animal, drove away quickly."  all the other of the OP's examples show that the verbs with ***ing*** function as action verbs: make, try and pass. Ergo, the one with the word painting does not work, and does not fit the pattern of the others. So,there's no point in trying to fit a square peg into a round hole here.